# Why does my notify() not work?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized, notify

None of my notifyAll() methods appear to be working.
Lucy is suppose to wait until Bob arrives and then release.
Bob is suppose to wait for acknowledgement Lucy and then release.
Neither of these things seem to be happening.

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong and how I can go about fixing it.
Thanks in advance.

Edit -  I amended my code using Grays advice.
The exception disappears but the notify() method still doesn't appear to be working.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PlayDates {
    Thread lucyThread;
    Girl lucy;
    Thread bobThread;
    Boy bob;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PlayDates playDates = new PlayDates();
        playDates.run();
    }
    public void run() {
        lucy = new Girl();
        lucyThread = new Thread(lucy);

        bob = new Boy();
        bobThread = new Thread(bob);

        lucyThread.start();
        threadSleep(500);
        bobThread.start();
    }

    public class Girl implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized(PlayDates.this){
                System.out.println("Girl synchronized hit");
                if(!bob.hasArrived()) {     // Doesnt seem to get past here?
                    System.out.println("Lucy has fallen asleep waiting for Bob");
                    try {
                        PlayDates.this.wait();  // Wait for Bob
                        System.out.println("Lucy has woken up");
                        PlayDates.this.notifyAll();     // Acknowledge Bobs arrival
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(PlayDates.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Boy implements Runnable {
        private boolean hasArrived;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized(PlayDates.this){
                System.out.println("Bob has arrived to play");
                PlayDates.this.notifyAll();
                try {
                    PlayDates.this.wait();  // Wait for Lucy to acknowledge Bobs arrival
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PlayDates.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

                System.out.println("Bob and Lucy are playing");
            }
        }

        public Boy() {
            hasArrived = true;
        }

        public boolean hasArrived() {
            return hasArrived;
        }
    }

    public void threadSleep(int milli) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(milli);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PlayDates.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Current Output

```
Girl synchronized hit
Bob has arrived to play
```

---

Edit 2
I've adapted my code as Grays advice suggests.
hasArrived is now volatile and in the playDates run method.
It's changed to true within the inner class Boys run method.
The output hasn't changed and the problem appears to be the same.
Any further advice?

Updated code:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PlayDates {
    Thread lucyThread;
    Girl lucy;
    Thread bobThread;
    Boy bob;
    volatile boolean hasArrived;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PlayDates playDates = new PlayDates();
        playDates.run();
    }
    public void run() {
        hasArrived = false;
        lucy = new Girl();
        lucyThread = new Thread(lucy);

        bob = new Boy();
        bobThread = new Thread(bob);

        lucyThread.start();
        threadSleep(500);
        bobThread.start();
    }

    public class Girl implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized(PlayDates.this){
                System.out.println("Girl synchronized hit");
                if(hasArrived) {     // Doesnt seem to get past here?
                    System.out.println("Lucy has fallen asleep waiting for Bob");
                    try {
                        PlayDates.this.wait();  // Wait for Bob
                        System.out.println("Lucy has woken up");
                        PlayDates.this.notifyAll();     // Acknowledge Bobs arrival
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(PlayDates.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Boy implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            threadSleep(1000);
            synchronized(PlayDates.this){
                System.out.println("Bob has arrived to play");
                hasArrived = true;
                PlayDates.this.notifyAll();
                try {
                    PlayDates.this.wait();  // Wait for Lucy to acknowledge Bobs arrival
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PlayDates.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                System.out.println("Bob and Lucy are playing");
            }
        }
    }

    public void threadSleep(int milli) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(milli);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PlayDates.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's tough to answer the question if you are editing it all of the time @James.  It invalidates our answers.  THis isn't supposed to be a forum.

Comment: @Gray I apologise, I am new.
In future, should i ask a new question with the amended code?

Comment: You could edit your answer and add a new section to the end.

Comment: @Gray Okay, that's what I'll do in the future.
My apologies.

Comment: Nw dude.  I've edited my answer with additional info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are starting the `Girl` thread before you initialize the `bob` field so you will get a NPE.  You should initialize your `bob` field *before* `Girl` and should pass it into that thread.  You program might work in certain situations but there is a race condition that is unpredictable.  If the thread starts fast enough, it may work but you should initialize `bob` *before* starting the `Girl` thread.

You also have some [memory synchronization issues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html).  For example, although you are synchronizing on `PlayDates.this`, the `Boy` class may not have been initialized and synchronized when the `Girl` thread calls `bob.hasArrived()`.  Whenever a field is accessed in multiple threads, you need to make sure that both threads are seeing a properly synchronized value.  You can ensure this by making `hasArrived` be an `AtomicBoolean` or by marking `hasArrived` as being `volatile`.

**Edit:**

The question is changing so I'll try to keep up.  What I would recommend is *not* to set `hasArrived` to be true in the `Boy` constructor.  I think you should make it `volatile` and set in in the `run()` method.  You want the `Girl` thread to start, run a bit, and then see that `Boy` is not available and `wait()`.  So the `Boy` thread should start later and set `hasArrived` to be `true` in it's `run()` method after a `sleep()`.

Comment: I want my Girl field to wait for the Bob field.
I've amended my code using your advice so that the NPE no longer gets thrown but the notify methods still dont appear to be working.

Comment: You just need to construct the `Bob` class _before_ calling `start()` on your `Girl` thread @James.

Comment: The second part of my answer may help with your synchronization issues @James.

Comment: Thank you for your advice so far. I've attempted to edit my code towards what you were suggesting. Unfortunately, the error has not changed. What have I missed?

Comment: Don't you mean `!hasArrived`?   You need to trace it in the code or learn how to use a debugger.  http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your advice and patience Gray. My program now works as expected.
I'll read the article on debugging and try to make good use of it.